# Beginner Objective-C, references to memory and pointers

Tags: objective-c, object, memory, reference

So this is an exercise in a book I am learning from. I got the exercise working fine, and I understand most of it, except, and,  I don't know if I am completely missing something here but...
How in the world does the compiler know that:

*x = 168.354 and y = 987.259 belong to (XYPoint*) pt*

and that

*x = 10.00 and y = 10.00 belong to (XYPoint*) t*

I understand how myPoint and myTranslate are separate objects in the XYPoint class and whatnot, and that they point to memory references where X and Y are stored, but how does it assign the above values to *pt* and *t*. Am I missing something huge here?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

Interface

```
#import "XYPoint.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Rectangle : NSObject

@property float width, height;

-(XYPoint*) origin;

-(void) translate: (XYPoint *)t;

-(void) setOrigin: (XYPoint *) pt;

-(float) area;

-(float) perimiter;

-(void) setHeight:(float) h andWidth: (float) w;



@end
Implementation

#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

@implementation Rectangle
{
    XYPoint *origin ;
}

@synthesize height, width;

-(void) setHeight: (float) h andWidth: (float) w;
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt
{
    if (! origin)
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
    
    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;
}


-(void) translate: (XYPoint*)t
{
    origin.x = origin.x + t.x;
    origin.y = origin.y + t.y;
    
    
}

-(float) area
{

    return width * height;
    
}

-(float) perimiter
{
    return (width + height) * 2;
}


-(XYPoint *) origin
{
    return origin;
}


@end
```

Main

```
#import "XYPoint.h"
#import "rectangle.h"
#import "Square.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        
        Rectangle *myRect = [[Rectangle alloc]init];
        XYPoint *myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
        XYPoint *myTranslate = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
        
        [myPoint setX: 168.354 andY: 987.259];
        [myTranslate setX: 10.00 andY: 10.00 ];
        

        myRect.origin = myPoint;
        
        NSLog (@"Origin at %f,  %f", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);
        
       
        [myRect translate: myTranslate];
        
        NSLog (@"Origin at %f,  %f", myRect.origin.x, myRect.origin.y);
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

Origin at 168.354004,  987.258972
Translated to 178.354004,  997.258972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t` and `pt` are not being assigned here, they are parameters to the functions `setOrigin:` and `translate:`.

they are the variables doing the assigning in the functions and not the other way round. they are used to update your origin `XYPoint`.

you dont seem to have a function that maps to this code here (well that i can see)

```
[myPoint setX: 168.354 andY: 987.259];
```

so im not sure if that function would call `setOrigin:` or `translate:` but that would 'assign' `t` and `pt` (as in they are arguments to your functions)

or regardless of that, you could set `pt` for example by just calling

```
[myPoint setOrigin:someOtherXYPointObject]; // someOtherXYPointObject here IS pt in this case
```

not sure if this answers your question

Comment: I forgot a file that I had with this code in it                     -(void) setX: (float) xVal andY: (float) yVal
{
    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;
}

Comment: yeah those dont really have anything to do with that. sorry i missed the line in you code `myRect.origin = myPoint;` this will automatically call `setOrigin:` for you. when you assign the origin variable, it will call its setter method. so `myRect.origin = myPoint;` and `[myRect setOrigin:myPoint]` are effectively the same thing (and myPoint in this case is `pt`). the translate below demonstrates that as well

Comment: Thanks. I think I am starting to understand better.